# Good way to draw two perpendicular lines at midpoint of a TikZ path

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics

What would be a good way to draw two perpendicular lines at the midpoint of a TikZ path, like in the following picture?

[image]

Specifically, what would be a good way to draw such perpendicular lines at the midpoint of the path between A and B in the following MWE?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) [below = of A] {B};
    \draw (A) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>NB: This question is tagged with [linguistics](/questions/tagged/linguistics) because such perpendicular lines are used for writing certain autosegmental phonology rules.</sup>

Comment: I's use a decoration. Would the to be decorated lines have any direction or will they always be vertical?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina They will not always be vertical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to use a decoration:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \draw (-1pt,-3pt) -- ++(0,6pt);
    \draw (1pt,-3pt) -- ++(0,6pt);
  }
}
]
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) [below left = of A] {B};
    \node (C) [below = of A] {C};
    \node (D) [above right = of A] {D};
    \draw[postaction=decorate] (A) to (B);
    \draw[postaction=decorate] (A) to (C);
    \draw[postaction=decorate] (C) to[out=30,in=30] (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must be getting old. The image is so small and hard to see. :)